# Google Chrome canvas v5 setLineDash

Tags: google-chrome, html5-canvas

Does anybody know since which version `context.setLineDash([5])` is implemented in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something on twitter:
http://goo.gl/ag7Vx

It looks like chrome supports setLineDash since version 23.

Answer (score 0):

you will probably find your answer in www.caniuse.com
search on the js api, it's a really handy website cos You can also use it for CSS and HTML tags and it tells you everything and on which browsers.

Comment: it says there that the canvas drawing was first fully supported in chrome 25 so i'm guessing that's what you are looking for :)

Comment: I know caniuse.com - there is only support for basic canvas methods listed.
Basic canvas methods are supported in chrome since chrome 4 (click "Show all versions") :)